# How to export a site from SharePoint online?

Tags: export, sharepoint-online

I've got a publishing site (root site, with subsites) containing web pages and documents (as do the subsites). I'd like to export it and restore it to a local SharePoint instance - any ideas how to achieve this?

I've tried exporting the site with content, but it's too big for that..

Comment: First I thought you could do this from PowerShell, but the command isn't available. Check the command builder: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/TechNet/en-us/Office/media/WindowsPowerShell/WindowsPowerShellCommandBuilder.html

Comment: How about doing a site collection backup through Central Administration: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748617.aspx? Never mind, might not be possible: http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/153/t/4830.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There's the excellent MetaVis Migration Tools @ http://www.metavistech.com/ - which should allow you to do this.

Alternately, you can open the document libraries in 'explorer view', copy them over, delete the files, and try to export the rest of the site?

Comment: MetaVis is a lifesaver so far.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Site Actions > Site Settings > Save site as template.

After the template is saved go to Site Actions > Site Settings > Solutions.

From there you can download your saved site template.

Comment: for those of us confused about where the link to download is, just click directly on the title of the solution :)

Comment: Has this option been removed? I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

I think at best you might just have to save the site as a template, but be mindful of the features that are avaliable on the sharepoint online platform because they might not appear on a sp 2010 on premise platform.